# jboss authenticate return http code 408

Tags: authentication, jboss, http-status-codes

I am trying to authenticate into JBoss,
and I got HTTP Status 408 - The time allowed for the login process has been exceeded.(full error message below)

this happens when I try to login using http://dnsname:8080/authenticate

if I replace this with just plain localhost ie http://localhost:8080/authenticate

then everything works fine.

What have I missed in the configuration ?

Environment:

- JBoss [Trinity] 4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA date=200710221139)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.5.0_22-b03,Sun Microsystems Inc.
- OS-System: Windows 7 6.1,amd64

Full Error message:

HTTP Status 408 - The time allowed for the login process has been exceeded. If you wish to continue you must either click back twice and re-click the link you requested or close and re-open your browser

---

type Status report

message The time allowed for the login process has been exceeded. If you wish to continue you must either click back twice and re-click the link you requested or close and re-open your browser

description The client did not produce a request within the time that the server was prepared to wait (The time allowed for the login process has been exceeded. If you wish to continue you must either click back twice and re-click the link you requested or close and re-open your browser).

---

JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if FQDN has "_" underscore character. Then IE corrupts cookies and session times out.

Comment: @temujin.ya.ru Thanks. That explains it.